# Error loading rmarkdown document after time period on shiny server

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

Cleaning up this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36564482/multiple-rmarkdown-files-on-shiny-server)

I am trying to deploy .Rmd files on a shiny server. This works at first i.e. when I first load the page everything loads correctly. It even loads two or three times. However, eventually it stops working and I get this error:

```
path[1]="/tmp/Rtmpcmbz6g/widgetbinding19405f628a16": No such file or directory
```

If I save the file in a new directory, it works again for a while then fails. The head of my .Rmd document looks like this:

```
---
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
---
```

In the document I import data from elsewhere on the server:

````
```{r, include=FALSE}
ERF <- 1001
ws <- paste("/media/erf_data/ERF",ERF,"/raw_data", sep="")
setwd(ws)
tdata <- paste("ERF", ERF, "_Transistor.csv", sep="")
tran <- read.csv(tdata)
```
````

This is my sessioninfo:

```
R version 3.2.4 Revised (2016-03-16 r70336)

Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] DT_0.1                dplyr_0.4.3           gridExtra_2.0.0       scales_0.3.0         
 [5] nlme_3.1-126          plyr_1.8.3            ggthemes_2.2.1        ggplot2_1.0.1        
 [9] splitstackshape_1.4.2 data.table_1.9.6      sqldf_0.4-10          RSQLite_1.0.0        
[13] gsubfn_0.6-6          proto_0.3-10          RMySQL_0.10.7         DBI_0.3.1            

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.2      formatR_1.2.1    tools_3.2.4      digest_0.6.8     jsonlite_0.9.19 
 [6] gtable_0.1.2     lattice_0.20-33  yaml_2.1.13      parallel_3.2.4   stringr_1.0.0   
[11] knitr_1.11       htmlwidgets_0.5  R6_2.1.1         tcltk_3.2.4      rmarkdown_0.9.5 
[16] reshape2_1.4.1   magrittr_1.5     htmltools_0.3    MASS_7.3-44      assertthat_0.1  
[21] colorspace_1.2-6 labeling_0.3     stringi_1.0-1    lazyeval_0.1.10  munsell_0.4.2   
[26] chron_2.3-47
```

Is there any more information I can provide that will help me find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I got this error, too.
It happens when I am hyperlinking a Shiny App page from a Rmd page. 
It works fine before you click on that hyperlink. After one click, the Rmd page will stop working giving me errors similar to yours.
The fix I found is to edit your Rmd file and save.
This seems to make Rmd refresh on the Shiny Server and solve this issue.
However, if you still want to hyperlink it, it will stop working the moment you click on it.

Comment: Thanks @bnelearner. Yes I found that if I save the .Rmd again then it works. My problem is that I am likley to have hundreds of .Rmd files with maybe 15 users, so I have no chance of refreshing each one every time somebody uses the page. I have resorted to knitting a .html doc for each .Rmd doc and sharing on dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

This may seem like a diff between server session timeout and caching. What's your configuration on this?

Comment: Let me find out, I need to contact the admin.